# "Com que " ou " Com qual"?

Tags: pronomes

Ao redigir um questionário, fiquei na dúvida entre estas duas frases abaixo. Qual está certa?

- "Com **qual frequência** as reuniões condominiais são realizadas?"
- "Com **que frequência** as reuniões condominiais são realizadas?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o mais adequado seja *com «qual»*, pois a palavra «frequência» *aparentemente* é **variável**, já que indica a presença de *desinência* de flexão de número (creio eu).

> Existem dois tipos de desinência nominais:
>
> - flexão de gênero (masculino e feminino)
> - flexão de número (singular e plural)

Primeiramente deixe-me explicar quando usar *«que»* e quando *«qual»*

O *pronome interrogativo* «que» é **invariável**, quando tem o sentido de «que coisa», por exemplo:

- Que é este embrulho?
- Que é esta caixa?
- Com que fez isto?

No entanto «que» deixa de ser [pronome](/questions/tagged/pronome) para ser [determinante](/questions/tagged/determinante), quando especifica algo, por tipo, especie, por exemplo:

- Pronome: Que (=coisa) procuras?
- Determinante: Que (=tipo) carro procuras?

> **Nota:** Um «pronome» substitui um nome, enquanto um «determinante» o antecede.

Já *pronome interrogativo* «qual» é **variável**, tem um valor seletivo, ou seja, quando se pretende selecionar, escolher uma entidade de entre várias. É usado, regra geral, antes do verbo **«ser»**.

Então apesar de ambas poderem ser usadas como **determinantes**, ainda sim a palavra «frequência» assume que é esperado um, nenhum ou mais horários (dias ou intervalos de tempo).

Fontes usadas para elaborar esta resposta:

- [O uso dos pronomes interrogativos que ou qual](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-dos-pronomes-interrogativos-que-ou-qual/24983)
- [Pronomes e determinantes interrogativos](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronomes-e-determinantes-interrogativos/20744)

Answer (score 2):

Ambas estão corretas (com uma ressalva). Mas nota que as duas opções  não são totalmente equivalentes, já que *qual* tem um valor seletivo. Essa ideia seletiva, por vezes algo esbatida, pode ser reforçada com *de + nome/pronome no plural* (construção partitiva):

> Com **qual das** frequências são as reuniões condominiais realizadas?

Portanto, ao usar *qual* temos um conjunto de possíveis frequências em mente, de entre as quais se pede para identificar uma.

A ressalva é que existem gramáticos que criticam o uso que propões de *qual*. Na *Gramática da Língua Portuguesa* de Maria Mateus e outras (8.a ed., pág. 464), temos a seguinte nota de rodapé:

> Certos gramáticos consideram que *qual* não deve ser usado imediatamente
>   seguido de nome e preferem o seu emprego em frases interrogativas predicativas como em *Qual é o hotel?*  ou em construções partitivas como *Qual dos senhores...?*

Pessoalmente, *com qual frequência são realizadas as reuniões* não me soa nada bem. Preferiria:

- Com que frequência são realizadas as reuniões?
- Qual é a frequência com que são realizadas as reuniões?
- Com qual das frequências são realizadas as reuniões?

escolhendo a última se quisesse reforçar a ideia seletiva (por exemplo, se estivessem em causa apenas duas possibilidades).

Comment: Penso da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0):

"Com que frequência são realizadas as reuniões?"

"Com qual frequência, diária ou semanal, são realizadas as reuniões?"